# System.IO.IOException on click of DataGridHyperlinkColumn WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid on a page in my **WPF** application,

[image: Application Data Grid]

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgMaster"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="15" IsReadOnly="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" ColumnWidth="Auto" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TASK ID}" Width="Auto" Header="Task ID"/>
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding Status}" Width="Auto" Header="Status">
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Name="btn" Click="btn_Click" Width="80">Close</Button>

</StackPanel>
```

Code behind and event handler method is below:

```
private void DG_Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
```

On `Hyperlink.Click` event, the code inside `DG_Hyperlink_Click` method gets executed, but after the method call, I get the below error and code freezes:

```
 System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232800
  Message=Cannot locate resource 'assigned'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
```

I want to open a new Window based on the value of status but not sure why I am getting this error.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see your `DG_Hyperlink_Click` code and it sounds pretty central to the question.

Comment: @grek40 I have added the method definition, and now you might have your vision back :P

Comment: I tried your code,it's working fine with the hyper link.I think error comes from some other function.

Comment: Can you remove everything unrelated (check what is needed to reproduce) and retry? Like how about removing `RowStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataGridRowHeader}"` and all the `DataGridTextColumn` columns.

Comment: I tried using just the grid and the binding, still in the code behind I get an error message : "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll"

Comment: You see, thats the whole point... if you can produce the error with less XAML and code, please do so for your question. Every line of code has the potential to distract and mislead people who are ready to help you. On the other hand, you need to include everything that's needed to reproduce the error. If I just put a DataGrid with a hyperlink column into a window, there is no error, so something else is needed and this something is not in the question.